# CSS POSITION:RELATIVE - Porque não usar só o absolute?

Tags: html, css, posicionamento

Se um position:absolute pode ser posicionado em qualquer lugar da pagina (inclusive de background) e ajustado com Z-index, porque é necessário o uso do position:relative?

Porque não usar somente o Position:Absolute?

Comment: Isso é relativo......

Comment: E o `position:absolute` seria em relação a qual referência?