# Position relative porque usar?

Tags: css

Porque usar o `position:relative`?

Se o `absolute` faz tudo em questão de posicionamento, porque não usar somente o `position:absolute` ao invés de usar os dois?

Comment: [Ontem você fez a mesma pergunta...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321218/css-positionrelative-porque-n%C3%A3o-usar-s%C3%B3-o-absolute#comment650735_321218)

Comment: `position: relative` faz com que elementos filhos com absolute se ajustem (top, left, bottom e right) ao elemento pai ao invés de se ajustar a página inteira. Ou seja se um elemento com position:absolute estiver dentro de um elemento com position:relative, a posição top:0 e left:0 vão ser baseada no elemento pai, se este elemento pai estiver no meio da página então a posição vai ser a partir deste local, ao invés do extremo da página. Resumindo, relative não é a mesma coisa que absolute e geralmente usamos ambas em conjunto.